# Nesting grids in MUI results in an unwanted row spacing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make nested grids, a grid that has two divs, one on the left and the other on the right, inside the left div, I want to have a grid system, there I want to add custom row spacing, but without adding anything related to row spacing, MUI is giving me row spacing, what could cause this problem?

```js
import React from 'react'
// MUI
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import Container from '@mui/material/Container'
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <>
      <Box className="login-page__bg">
        <Container sx={{ py: 5 }}>
          <Paper elevation={2}>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item container md={6}>
                {/* <Container sx={{ py: 5 }}> */}
                <Grid item sm={12}>
                  <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                    Login to your account
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={12}>
                  <TextField label="Your Email" type="email" variant="standard" fullWidth />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={12}>
                  <TextField label="Password" type="password" variant="standard" fullWidth />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={12}>
                  <Button variant="outlined" color="success" size="large" fullWidth>
                    Login
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
                {/* </Container> */}
              </Grid>

              <Grid item md={6} sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'block' } }}>
                <Box className="login-page__rightBgimg" />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is a bug in MUI, it's not how  it's supposed to act based on the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

**Answer summary:** Don't use the `container` and `item` props at the same time, if you need to do so, nest them in separate Grid components.

Yes this is a bug in MUI, and I managed to fix it by separating the `item` from `container`.

for any facing the same problem. I was able to fix it by nesting a container inside an item. What I was doing is that I was having the two props (container, item) on the same grid component.

What you should do to fix this is to nest them inside each other instead of having them in one line:

Working code now:

```js
    <>
      <Box className="login-page__bg">
        <CssBaseline />
        <Container sx={{ py: 5 }}>
          <Paper elevation={3}>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item sm={12} md={6}>
                <Container sx={{ py: 5 }}>
                  <Grid container rowSpacing={4}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} variant="h5">
                        Login To Your Account
                      </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <TextField label="Your Email" type="email" variant="standard" fullWidth />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <TextField label="Password" type="password" variant="standard" fullWidth />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                      <Button variant="outlined" color="success">
                        Login
                      </Button>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Container>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sm={false} md={6}>
                <div className="login-page__rightBgimg" />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
```

Or in colored picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because on left Grid as you have added all the elements in separate grid and grid has a property to adjust.
Just try to remove grid and use div instead.

Comment: this results in the following : https://ibb.co/RgZrJyc

Comment: I want to add a row spacing, but not that much, I just want it to be a row spacing of two, but MUI is pushing everything away

Comment: https://ibb.co/DzgR8bT

Comment: Make a div inside grid and then again make sub div.

Comment: can you demonstrate this in an answer?

Comment: Provide me with all the code .Css too

Comment: okay one minute

Comment: here https://file.io/8sXvOxJk5ZhO   when you start the app, go to `/login`

Comment: did you know how to fix it?

Comment: I will make it work how you want. Will that be fine.

Comment: I think its a MUI bug I'll create a report on their github

Answer (score 0):

Make a main div inside grid and then again make sub div inside main div. After that you can adjust the row size and even the the positioning of main div.